# Export GPIO pins from extender

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

I have PCF8574 GPIO extender connected to RPi. I use GPIO Sysfs. It is possible to write/read to/from extender pins, using command like this:

```
gpio -x pcf8574:352:32 read 358
```

But i can not export such pin. What is the correct syntax to export pin like this above? Any idea?

Comment: Is the PCF8574 known to sysfs?  The wiringPi gpio command has nothing to do with sysfs.

Comment: Of course, WiringPi has nothing to SysFS. But Domoticz app use build-in own interface to sysfs bo control GPIO pins. But first such pin must be `export` using `gpio` command. Thats my problem because it is possible to export on-board pins but can not export expander pins. But it is possible to fully control it.

Answer (score 2):

I am reasonably certain that wiringPi's `gpio` command can't be used to interface with the expander in this way from the command line.

You'll likely want to interface it by writing your own binary. Please see [this document](http://wiringpi.com/extensions/i2c-pcf8574/) on Gordon's site for further details.

Said GPIO expander is an i2c device, and must be treated as such.

Comment: This may and possibly should be a comment. Please flag it up if you agree and I will remove this post, as I'm unsure if OP is focusing more on wiringPi's `gpio`, or sysfs.

Comment: I can not flag answer because of my "reputation". But I flag it down. It is possinle to set direction, read and write from/to expander using `GPIO` command. See example in the first post.  in this example if I short pin 6 to ground, I get result "0". If I leave it open the result is "1". And more. If I connect relay via transistor, it is possible tu turn it on and off using command `gpio -x pcf8574:352:32 write 358 1 (or 0)`. But I can not `export` such pin (syntax error).